# Как писать красивый и читаемый код?

Tags: code-style, style-guide

1. Максимальное сокращение кода.
   Бывает желания максимально сократить код, но появляются сомнения, не перебор ли это. Ведь можно было бы  отдельно объявить переменную и ей уже присвоить выражение, которое без переменной не сразу понятно что делает.
2. Именование переменных.
   Проблемы с выбором имени для переменной. Если описывать полностью, что она делает, то будет около 16 символов, а если сокращать, то может конфликтовать с пониманием других переменных. Контекст тоже не всегда спасает.
3. Разделение действий.
   Слишком много всего в одной части кода, что может усложнить понимание. С одной стороны можно было бы вынести в отдельные функции, а с другой стороны нет смысла, так как используются только в той части кода.
4. Уместность комментариев.
   Свой код всегда понятен, а предположить как его понимают другие, будет не всегда объективно. Так что, не всегда очевидно, нужен комментарий или он будет избыточен.
5. Форматирование.
   С большой или маленькой буквы начинать переменную, а также в пределах переменной нужно ли большими буквами начинать слова или же разделять их с помощью "_". Делать ли пустую строку между if и другими блоками, а также между переменными и этими блоками или же расставлять по действиям. Делать ли отступы внутри выражений, к примеру if( sometring ) или if(sometring).
   6...

Эти пункты только для понимания проблемы, потому что многие забыл, а многие и не замечал, думаю. А также на эти пункты с одной стороны очень легко ответить, а с другой хотелось бы правил или детального разбора.
Так вот, есть ли правила гласные/негласные, в которых бы описывалось это и многое другое в этом направлении? Или есть книги посвященные этой теме?

Comment: Я вам рекомендую к обязательному прочтению "Совершенный код" http://goo.gl/jiEHE1 и "Чистый код" http://goo.gl/rtF5wD

Comment: И продолжение "Чистого кода", которое называется "Идеальный программист" http://goo.gl/yD6VJb

Comment: @Shamov по-моему, в "Идеальном программисте" нет ни слова о том, как писать хороший и красивый код. Там о том, как самому вести себя хорошо и красиво с профессиональной т.з.

Comment: @andreycha Строго говоря, да... конкретных указаний там нет. Но с учётом того, что хороший код может писать только хороший человек, там вся книга об этом.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Вопрос стиля — на самом деле очень серьёзный вопрос.

Не забывайте, что код пишется вами *не* для компилятора. Сделать, чтобы было понятно компилятору просто, но ваша цель сложнее: сделать так, чтобы было понятно *человеку*.

Код программы — то же самое литературное произведение.  Вы должны донести мысль читателю, причём этим читателем можете оказаться как вы сами через полгода, так и ваш коллега, которому придётся править код пока вы в отпуске.

Хороший код живёт долго, а значит, он будет прочитан, подправлен, понят и объяснён много раз. Понимание чужого кода гораздо сложнее, чем написание нового с нуля, поэтому инвестировать в понятность кода важно (если, конечно, вы желаете своему коду долгой счастливой жизни).

**Сокращение кода** *не нужно*. Код должен быть понятным, не больше и не меньше.

Если вам кажется, что где-то нужно расписать для наглядности — так и сделайте, даже пусть придётся вводить дополнительные переменные только чтобы дать имя промежуточному результату. Если, наоборот, вам кажется, что кода слишком много для той простой штуки, которую он делает — вынесите эту штуку в отдельную функцию и придумайте ей правильное название, чтобы пояснить смысл действия. Поддерживайте однородность и общий темп: если кусок кода запускает космическую ракету в полёт, то кусок кода рядом с ним, который читает данные из конфигурационного файла, смотрится нелепо.

**Именование переменных и функций**. Не жалейте букв! Байты на винчестере подешевели. Вы не должны писать комментарии, чтобы пояснить смысл переменной, иначе читатель должен видеть одно (имя переменной), а в уме держать другое (её смысл). С другой стороны, не надоедайте читателю излишними подробностями. То, что у вас не просто `acceptableByteCount`, а `countOfBytesWhichDidNotPassAtLeastTwoFilters`, — скучно. Соблюдайте разумный баланс. Если вам нужна переменная цикла, назовите её `i` или `j`, это стандартная практика. Придерживайтесь общепринятых соглашений, если нужно, придумывайте свои (но разумные!), легко понятные другим.

Именуйте переменные правильно. Название должно отображать смысл. Если вы используете одну и ту же переменную в двух разных смыслах, вы делаете неправильно, разделите её на две переменные с однозначным смыслом. Например, не стоит совмещать длину переданной строки и счётчик оставшихся символов для обработки, хотя начальное значение счётчика и совпадает с длиной строки.

Старайтесь, чтобы текст читался естественно. Например, имя действия должно бы быть глаголом (не `vector.Normalization()`, а `vector.Normalize()` или `vector.GetNormal()`). Имя булевого условия должно быть *похоже* на условие и скорее всего начинаться с `is`, `has` и тому подобного. (Например: `hasChanges()`, `isPrime()` и т. п.) Ради бога, используйте английские имена, а не русские транслитом! Поверьте, `isZarplataComputed()` смотрится ужасно. Исключение — языки с кириллическим синтаксисом ([1с](/questions/tagged/1%d1%81)?) или общепринятый стиль команды.

**Разделение действий**. Да, имеет смысл отделять код в функцию только для того, чтобы правильно назвать этот фрагмент кода. Функции существуют *не* для повторного использования! Функции нужны для логического разбиения кода на части. Если вы видите, что ваша функция ответственна за разные вещи, и вы не можете придумать ей короткого точного названия, значит, ваша функция делает чересчур много, и её надо разделить. Часто из супердлинной функции в 500 строк получается десяток классов. И это хорошо.

И да, читателю гораздо лучше понять функцию, которая делает *одну* простую задачу. Если функция делает слишком много, у неё кроме более сложного кода более сложные пред- и постусловия (а значит, её ещё сложнее понять).

Для хорошего разбиения на части проектируйте сверху вниз. Пример: приготовить еду — это что? Решаем, что это значит приготовить французский завтрак. Окей, а что такое приготовить французский завтрак? Это купить круассаны и сварить кофе. А что такое сварить кофе? Это смолоть зёрна в кофемолке, засыпать в турку, добавить воды, поместить на огонь, и т. д. Это естественным образом оформляется в процедуры `CookMeals`, `CookFrenchBreakfast`, `BuyCroissants`, `MakeCoffee`. Ничего выдумывать не пришлось.

**Уместность комментариев**. Старайтесь писать код так, чтобы комментарии не были нужны. Очень часто комментарии избыточны; очень часто они устаревают и перестают отображать действительность. Люди часто меняют логику кода, но забывают пробежаться и по комментариям.

Не забывайте, что выполняется код, а не комментарии. Поэтому ошибочный, вводящий в заблуждение комментарий (например: `/* здесь не может получиться NULL */`) гораздо хуже его отсутствия. Если у вас есть кусок кода, снабжённый комментарием, объясняющим, что он делает, превратите этот код в функцию, а комментарий — в её имя. Полностью избежать комментариев, вероятно, не удастся, но постарайтесь, чтобы комментарии описывали, *почему* вы делаете так, как делаете, а *что именно* вы делаете, должно быть понятно из кода.

**Форматирование**. Плохое форматирование очень сильно влияет на читаемость кода. Выработайте стиль и придерживайтесь его. Какой именно стиль вы выберете, в общем-то и не важно, главное, чтобы он был логичен и последователен. (Например, если вы ставите пробел после `while`, наверное стоит ставить пробел и после `if`.) Старайтесь, тем не менее, не отступать от общепринятых соглашений (например, имена методов в Java принято выбирать в lowerCamelCase), иначе вам трудно будет читать чужой код.

Если вы работаете в команде, не нарушайте общий стиль, даже если вам персонально он не нравится. Если в команде нету общепринятого стиля, предложите его! Расстановка скобок, отступы, пробелы, максимальная длина строк и всё такое важны, чтобы читатель не отвлекался. Непоследовательное форматирование сбивает с толку и отвлекает гораздо больше, чем это кажется — точно так же, как неправильная пунктуация мешает правильно понимать текст литературного произведения.

---

И последнее. Не заботьтесь о повышении эффективности кода путём понижения его читаемости. Выделение отдельного метода — не проблема, современные компиляторы научились inline-ить всё, что нужно. И объединять разные переменные в один регистр они скорее всего умеют гораздо лучше вас. Если же в каком-то месте ради низкоуровневой оптимизации действительно нужно ухудшить читаемость, снабдите этот фрагмент достаточными комментариями по поводу того, что же происходит в коде, и самое главное — почему такой трюк понадобился.

Answer (score 16):

Первое, что хотелось бы сказать - это очень хороший вопрос.

То, что вы ищете, называется *конвенцией написания кода* (или *стандартами написания кода*), и их легко найти по запросу "coding style convention" или "coding standards". Для С / С++ существуют несколько конвенций, какую конкретно вы будете использовать - как правило, не имеет значения, главное, чтобы весь проект был выдержан в одном ключе. Первыми ссылками выпадают конвенции от [гугла](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html) (С++) и [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/) c [Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) (С) - я их не читал, но они должны в полной мере покрывать вышеописанные вопросы.

Что касается комментариев - это довольно спорная позиция, тут придется вырабатывать свою стратегию. Многие считают, что код должен читаться сам по себе без комментариев; такие, как я, эту стратегию поддерживают, но считают, что комментарии должны максимально разжевывать возможное использование (чтобы банально высвечиваться в IDE).

Answer (score 16):

Я пишу на PHP, Python и Javascript, но все-же позволю себе оставить пару домыслов (они касаются твоего 2го пункта). Именно этот пункт доставил моей команде немало хлопот, после разрастания проекта.

У нас есть внутренний протокол (JSON поверх TCP), с помощью которого компоненты системы общаются друг с другом, назовем его, допустим... TMP-протокол.

Есть не один десяток сущностей, которые имею прямое отношение к TMP - всякие интерфейсы, гейтвеи, колбэки, "обещания", ожидающие ответ и тд и тп.

НИКОГДА нельзя давать названия классам и переменным, которые не дают примерного понятия о своем предназначении, **например**:

```
class TmpProtocol
```

Protocol в данном случае - это лишние 8 символов (tmp - это и так протокол), название класса не говорит вообще ни о чем. **Сравните с этим**:

```
class TmpClientGateway
```

Лучше? Намного! Интуитивно хочется сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
$a = new TmpClientGateway();
$a->makeRequest(...)
```

Теперь по поводу переменных.
Если переменная имеет хоть какое-то значение во внешнем мире, то и ей нужно давать осмысленное название, например следующий код вскружит голову и доведет вас до тошноты:

```
self.deferred = defer.Deferred()
```

Мы пообещали кому-то (не важно кому) отложенный результат. Но вот, что мы пообещали - никому не понятно (и вы сами забудете через год). Куда лучше написать что-нибудь в таком духе:

```
self.serverResponse = defer.Deferred()
```

Нужно себе отдавать отчет в том, что эта конкретная штука делает и называть ее соответствующим образом. И мешанина из классов, обслуживающих tmp:

```
class tmpProtocol, class Handler, class tmpInterface
```

превращается в что-то более понятное:

```
class tmpServerRequest, class tmpServerRequestFactory, class tmpMethodDecorator
```

И еще, если некий класс - наследник от какого-то стандартного Factory, то и переменные этого нового класса в названии должны содержать Factory, а не, скажем, Handler

Теперь насчет 3го пункта:
Не заставляйте один и тот же кусок кода обрабатывать ошибку tcp-соединения и ошибку, скажем, "нецелостности" пришедших данных (даже если сверху, для пользователя, эти ситуации выглядят одинаково).

Это сделает код абсолютно непрозрачным. Гораздо лучше разнести функционал по двум, пусть даже и почти одинаковым, функциям и избежать непонятных ветвлений из if-else-elsif-elsif.

Особенно сводит с ума, когда в теле els`ов происходит нечто почти одинаковое, но отличающееся, на 1 строчку (в одном елсе - вручную закрыли, сокет, а в другом - не стали этого делать).

Будет намного понятнее, если первую ситуацию обработает функция errCorruptedData (данные пришли, но кривые, поэтому сокет закроем!) , a вторую ситуацию - errNoRouteToHost (сокет и так не открылся).

Прошу прощения за вырожденные примеры.

Answer (score 13):

Качество вашего С кода в основном зависит от вашего же практического опыта и степени просветеления. Кроме этого в каждом крупном проекте свои причуды по поводу форматирования.

Поэтому отвечу по пунктам вопроса, воспользовавшись негласной(уже нет) конвенцией, что я обычно использую когда пишу C код.

1. Two or more use a for(c). Сокращаю только в том случае если с помощью этого можно автоматизировать весь процесс. Никогда не допускаю китайского кода.
2. Всегда использую длинные и понятные идентификаторы в нижнем регистре разделенные `_` из которых сразу ясен контекст и вся дополнительная информация. Никогда не сокращаю их. `very_long_clear_and_useful_variable_name`. Никогда не использую венгерскую нотацию с информацией о типе в идентификаторе.
3. Создаю столько наиболее подходящих абстракций сколько нужно для решения задачи, не больше.Также по возможности следую жесткому эмпирическому правилу гласящему что: 
   *Не автоматически сгенерированная функция в которой есть либо строки длиннее 80 символов, либо больше 3 уровней вложенности инструкций потока управления, либо больше 3 вложенных скобочных пар в одной строке, либо больше 40 строк, либо получающая больше 3 параметров(variadic считается за 1), либо в коде которой есть больше 0 явно написанных чисел или строковых констант с вероятностью близкой к 100% никому не нужна во внешнем мире и сгодится только в качестве учебного примера или для аккуратного внутреннего пользования.*

   > Каждый раз когда вы вставляете в продакшн фукнцию, которая не удоволетворяет правилу одна звезда на небе гаснет, толпа школьников садистов заживо препарирует хомячка, а в мозгу ваших коллег читающих её умирают нейроны.
4. Вообще не использую комментарии в определениях, вместо них делаю принудительную выгрузку в дебаг лог. В объявлениях вставляю только шапку и краткое описание того что делает этот файл.
5. `МАКРОСЫ` большими буквами, все остальное маленькими через _. Использую K&R отсупы. `DeprecatedCamelCaseIdentifiers` не использую. Использую суффикс `_t`, чтобы отличать, объявленные через `typedef` структуры от всего остального.

Хотя конечно сколько конвенций не применяй С код вообще довольно сложно сделать легкочитаемым.

В подтверждении этого можно посмотреть [международный конкурс самых запутанных программ на C.](http://www.ioccc.org/)

Вот, например, типичная программа оттуда, которая просто рисует огромный смайлик, показывающий язык, в терминале:

```
m(f,a,s)char*s;
{char c;return f&1?a!=*s++?m(f,a,s):s[11]:f&2?a!=*s++?1+m(f,a,s):1:f&4?a--?
 putchar(*s),m(f,a,s):a:f&8?*s?m(8,32,(c=m(1,*s++,"Arjan Kenter. \no$../.\""),
 m(4,m(2,*s++,"POCnWAUvBVxRsoqatKJurgXYyDQbzhLwkNjdMTGeIScHFmpliZEf"),&c),s)):
 65:(m(8,34,"rgeQjPruaOnDaPeWrAaPnPrCnOrPaPnPjPrCaPrPnPrPaOrvaPndeOrAnOrPnOrP\
nOaPnPjPaOrPnPrPnPrPtPnPrAaPnBrnnsrnnBaPeOrCnPrOnCaPnOaPnPjPtPnAaPnPrPnPrCaPn\
BrAnxrAnVePrCnBjPrOnvrCnxrAnxrAnsrOnvjPrOnUrOnornnsrnnorOtCnCjPrCtPnCrnnirWtP\
nCjPrCaPnOtPrCnErAnOjPrOnvtPnnrCnNrnnRePjPrPtnrUnnrntPnbtPrAaPnCrnnOrPjPrRtPn\
CaPrWtCnKtPnOtPrBnCjPronCaPrVtPnOtOnAtnrxaPnCjPrqnnaPrtaOrsaPnCtPjPratPnnaPrA\
aPnAaPtPnnaPrvaPnnjPrKtPnWaOrWtOnnaPnWaPrCaPnntOjPrrtOnWanrOtPnCaPnBtCjPrYtOn\
UaOrPnVjPrwtnnxjPrMnBjPrTnUjP"),0);}

main(){return m(0,75,"mIWltouQJGsBniKYvTxODAfbUcFzSpMwNCHEgrdLaPkyVRjXeqZh");}
```

Она вполне рабочая. Какая уж тут конвенция.

P.S. Чтобы немного облегчить понимание сложных объявлений вроде такого:

`char **(*(*(*x)[100])(int,char*,double ***,void(*)(int**,char[])))[50];`

> На самом деле тут все просто и понятно. `x` это просто указатель на массив из 100 указателей на функцию принимающую аргументы (`int`, указатель на `char`, указатель на указатель на указатель на `double`, указатель на функцию принимающую (указатель на указатель на  `int`, массив `char`) возвращающую `void`) возвращающую указатель на массив из 50 указтелей на указателей на `char`

можно воспользоваться [их переводчиком на английский](http://cdecl.org)

Answer (score 8):

Прежде всего нужно сказать, что ответа на этот вопрос нет. На обе его части...

Понятие красоты вообще нерелевантно коду. Код не может быть красивым. Это не стихи, и не проза. И он не должен быть красивым. Его задача состоит не в том, чтобы доставлять кому-то эстетическое удовольствие, а в том, чтобы компилироваться. У него сугубо инструментальная функция. Наверняка, бывают люди, которым разнообразные конструкции циклов и условных операторов нравятся чисто эстетически, но это скорее перверсия... не нужно ориентироваться на таких людей. Хотя нужно отметить, что красивым может быть алгоритм, который реализован в коде. Но надо эти вещи чётко разделять. Назвать какой-то код красивым - это всё равно, что назвать красивым железобетон, из которого построено красивое здание.

Что же касается читаемости кода, то с этим дело обстоит получше. Хотя и на эту часть вопроса ответа тоже нет. В индустрии широко распространено ошибочное мнение, будто бы читаемость - это свойство самого кода... будто бы коду можно придать такую форму, которая сделает его читаемым. В действительности это не так. Код не может быть читаемым сам по себе... отдельно от того, кто его читает. Это более-менее очевидная мысль. Но, к сожалению, мало кто об этом задумывается. На самом деле, нужно думать о читаемости кода не как о свойстве самого кода, а как об отношении между двумя и более людьми, которое каким-то неуловимым образом встроено в тот код, который они пишут и читают. Если у каждого из этих людей получается писать код так, что другие могут читать и понимать его более-менее комфортно, то значит эти люди пишут читаемый код. Но эта читаемость неразрывно связана с этими конкретными людьми. Нельзя передать код другим людям, сохранив при этом его читаемость на прежнем уровне. У других людей в мозгу будут уже сформированы совсем другие паттерны, связанные с кодом, и потому читаемость любого кода, который в них не вписывается, обязательно просядет.

Пресловутые Coding Style Guides в действительности подходят к решению проблемы именно со стороны людей. Их задача состоит лишь в том, чтобы зафиксировать некий набор разумных правил, которых люди, работающие вместе, соглашаются придерживаться. Не потому, что эти правила чем-то объективно хороши, а просто потому, что конкретно им такой набор правил наиболее удобен в качестве общего.

В пункте 4 очень точно схвачена суть проблемы, хотя речь там идёт о комментариях. "Свой код всегда понятен." - Эту фразу нужно мысленно повторять три раза всякий раз, когда возникает желание вынести какое-либо суждение о своём собственном коде. В том числе и о его читаемости. Ну, или можно слегка изменить фразу: "Свой код всегда читаем."

В общем, вне всякой связи с людьми коду можно придать лишь такие свойства как правильность, компилируемость, эффективность и т.д. Свойство же читаемости существует в коде в форме чего-то эфемерного, что связывает этот код с какими-то конкретными людьми. И чтобы оценить код на читаемость, нужно показать его другим людям. Причём не просто другим случайным людям, а именно тем, у которых есть личная заинтересованность в том, чтобы его читать и понимать. Другого способа нет. Если же код интересен только самому автору, и он сам может его комфортно читать, то значит код уже читаем на 100%. Ничего больше делать не нужно. Повысить читаемость выше 100% нельзя.

Comment: Красота понятие эстетическое и конечно же, субъективное, т.е. связано с внутренним миром человека, с той моделью реальности, которая в голове у каждого из нас. Кто-то видит ее в природных объектах, кто-то в картинах, а кто-то в музыке... Так что нет ничего удивительного, когда определенная часть людей говорит о красоте кода.

Answer (score 7):

К каждому языку - свой подход. Для тех же C и C++ ответ на некоторые пункты может быть совершенно разным.

1. Сокращение количества кода иногда бывает плюсом, т.к. рыться в колоссальном codebase часто неприятно, а мерянье количеством KLoC в своих проектах - дурацкое занятие. Но надо не переборщить. У нас тут, знаете ли, не [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) =) код всегда должен быть читаемым, даже для человека, видящего его в первый раз!
2. Именование переменных. Это дело вкуса, но важно, чтобы имя переменной предоставляло хоть какую-нибудь информацию о том, что она такое есть.
3. ИМХО самый важный пункт, здесь распишу (немного побольше, чем спрашивалось, ну да ладно) с конкретикой для С, т.к. имею с ним некоторый опыт. Что-то из этого применимо к другим языкам. Заранее предупреждаю, все далее - чисто мое ИМХО.

   В любом C-коде главное - баланс.

   Важно соблюдать баланс между стремлением сделать код модульнее и реюзабельнее, добавляя в него больше специализированных функций, и созданием слишком длинных, неоптимальных и уж точно нечитаемых цепочек вызовов функций (инлайнить умеют далеко не все C-компиляторы, а стэк не резиновый, и фреймы не моментально создаются).

   Баланс должен быть между тем, что берет на себя ваше API, и тем, что оно взваливает на пользователя (вызывающий API код). Например, есть негласное правило - если API инициализирует только что созданный объект, аллокацию памяти под этот объект надо оставить пользователю.

   Баланс должен быть между количеством функций, globals-ов, прототипов функций и макросов в одном файле (и в одном translation unit-е). С одной стороны, сильно набивать ни файл, ни translation unit нехорошо, но с другой стороны, и создавать отдельный файл для одной функции неоправданно.

   И, конечно же, баланс должен быть между тем, что кому и где видно. Если кто вам скажет, что в C нет энкапусляции, не верьте, она там была задолго до C++ и его модификатора `private`! =) Чтобы энкапуслировать функцию или global, объявите ее статической (`static`) в отдельном translation-unit-е, тогда к ней можно будет получить доступ только из него же. Чтобы энкапуслировать членов структуры, используйте ее как `opaque pointer` - это можно сделать, например, объявив ее как incomplete type в коде, вызывающем энкапсулирующее API, а определить ее уже в самом API (хороший пример [тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C)).
4. Комментарии - это хорошо. Но нельзя на них слишком сильно полагаться. Если код плохо написан, то тут никакие комментарии не спасут. Опять же, нужен баланс - комментариев не должно быть мало (за исключением *очень* редких случаев, когда код благодаря красноречивым именам функций/переменных и т.д. и логичного построения алгоритмов читаем сам по себе), но и не должно быть много (как в поговорке: 90% комментариев, 10% кода<s>, но все равно нихрена не понимаю, что этот код делает</s>).
5. Стиль - это лично ваше дело. Конечно, у некоторых языков есть идиоматический стиль, которого стараются все придерживаться (например, C# с майкрософтовским стилем, или Java со стилем примеров из Javadoc). Проблема в том, что у C их что собак нерезанных. Кто-то пишет код, как в примерах в книге K&R, кто-то следует формату Linux Kernel - а, кто-то предпочитает формат Столлмана... Вот [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) энное количество примеров кода разных стилей. Вообще, стиль себе каждый программист должен выбрать сам (лично я, например, даже на C пишу на чем-то сродни стилю Javadoc-а, с camelCase-ом и индентацией, похожей на BSD KNF). И, конечно, на каждом себя уважающем предприятии есть свой, иногда уникальный, style-guide, определяющий, КАК должен выглядеть код, так что надо уметь адаптироваться к другим стилям.

Comment: Вы пишете `есть негласное правило - если API инициализирует только что созданный объект, аллокацию памяти под этот объект надо оставить пользователю` -- ссылки на *авторитетные* (правда, тут вопрос -- для кого) источники можно? Возможно правильней не обязывать а предоставить возможность (т.е. тут речь  об разных уровнях API). / Ну, и насколько хороша практика сокрытия полей структур -- тоже спорный вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

Буду отвечать общими принципами - они сами подходят к Си++, но примеры буду приводить те, которые приходят в голову, не обязательно на плюсах.

1. Код должен быть кратким. Но не максимально.
   Например, я как-то переписал несколько экранов разметки на несколько строк (html, AngularJS). И добавил комментарий, описывающий, что там вообще происходит.
   А вот пример на VB.NET, когда сокращение кода - это жесть:
   `X *= 10` - 5 значащих символов
   `X &= 0` - 4 значащих символа и жуткий оверхед при выполнении: сначала мы конвертируем числа X и 0 в строки, потом создаём новую строку выполнив конкатенацию, потом парсим получившуюся строку обратно в число и выполняем присваивание. Место такому коду - только в codegolf-задачках, больше нигде.
   В чрезмерно ужатом коде разобраться может быть очень сложно, а уж на Си++ - особенно.
2. На мой взгляд, имена переменных должны быть краткими. Но при этом осмысленными. И без излишних сокращений. Да, я могу понять, что такое `s2e` в  `<a id=s2e>Switch to English</a>`, но на мой взгляд, такие сокращения оправданы только для частоиспользуемых вещей, а в остальных случаях их применять не следует. И я не люблю распространённые сокращения `tmp` и `cnt` - эти 1 - 2 символа не стоят того.
3. Всё по ситуации. Если есть осмысленный блок, который хочется вынести в функцию - то да. Если нет, то не надо. Если вынесение вызывает проблемы, то тоже не надо. Как вариант - написать комментарий, что делает конкретный участок кода и поставить обрамляющие этот участок фигурные скобки, чтобы блок был выделен явно:

   ```
   // Сделать что-то
     {
     ТутКакойТоДлинныйКод();
     }
   ```

   Чрезмерное выделение функций на каждый чих мне не нравится. Да, некоторые любят, когда код можно читать как текст, но код обычно читают не чтобы полюбоваться, а чтобы что-то в нём изменить. И искать нужное место, когда перед тобой почти текст, а не код мне очень неудобно.
4. Комментарии должны говорить об идее кода или пояснять какие-то сложные моменты. Пояснять то, что можно понять из кода, обычно не стоит. Единственное исключение, это когда код делает что-то совсем неочевидное. Имеет смысл пояснять какие-то подводные камни и ограничения, а так же высокоуровневые описания. Имеет смысл отмечать комментарием то, что при первом взгляде кажется ошибкой. Например, присваивания в условиях и отсутствие break в switch'е.
5. Про заглавные буквы комментировать не буду.
   Что касается отступов - почти всегда пропускаю строку перед и после блоками.
   Предпочитаю не ставить фигурные скобки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424351/178988.
   Не пишу несколько операторов в одной строке просто так.
   Допускаю возможность использования запятой.
   Если есть основания выровнять похожие строки столбцами - делаю это. Это единственный случай помещения нескольких операторов в строку.