# Проблема с участками кода в создании программы архиватора в бинарном формате

Tags: c#

У меня критическая проблема с кодом. Я пишу программу на C#, использую microsoft visual studio 2010 ultimate.

```
private void Button_ExtractArchive2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult a = this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    ///this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog( .OpenFile();

    if (a == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
        //string path = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
        // filename = path + "note.txt";

        // запись в файл
        //using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(@"I:\SomeDir\noname\note.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))


        //FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"C:\test.bin");

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"D:\test.bin");

        using (FileStream fs = f.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {        

             // преобразуем строку в байты
             // считываем данные

             using (BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader (fs))
             {
                 char DOF = 'ĩ';

                 for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++)
                 {
                     // считываем очередной символ из открытого для чтения файла - ВЫЯСНИТЬ КАК

                      using (var stream = File.OpenText("some.csv"))
                      {                                
                          string line = stream.ReadLine(); // следующий символ
                          while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null) // line[1], line[2]
                          {
                              var columns = line.Split(',');
                              // Тут данные для каждого столбца присвоить полям структуры
                           }
                       }

                       int digit = -1; // переменная для хранения цифры, если ее удастся считать

                       // пытаемся перевести символ в число с помощью функции TryParse - ВЫЯСНИТЬ КАК

                       Int64.TryParse(line, out digit);
                       if (digit >= 0 && digit <= 9)   // если получили цифру
                       {

                           // добавляем символ в массив цифр -  ВЫЯСНИТЬ КАК
/*                                                              
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
array<int>^ arr;
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        arr->Resize(arr,arr->Length+1);
        arr[arr->Length-1]=1;
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
};



IList^ arr;
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        arr->Add(1);
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //


array<CSustav^>^ close;
CSustav::CSustav(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    close=gcnew array<CSustav^>(100);
}
*/
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // иначе обрабатываем спецсимволы и выходим из цикла
                         break;
                         }
                     }
                     Int64 count = 0; // ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ СЧИТЫВАНИЯ ЧИСЛА БАЙТ!!!
                     // далее, если массив цифр непустой, получаем число из цифр - ВЫЯСНИТЬ КАК
                     count += Math.Pow(10, the_degree) * the_digit;

                     // здесь the_degree - степень числа 10, вычисляемая в цикле
                     // the_digit - ранее записанная в массив цифра по индексу этого цикла
                     count += 1 * 4 + 10 * 1 + 100 * 5 + 1000 * 4 + 10000 * 3 + 100000 * 2 + 1000000 * 1 + 10000000 * 1 + 100000000 * 1 + 1000000000 * 1;
                     count += 1 * 4; //4  надо объенидить в единый (как?)...
                     count += 10 * 1; //14 при этих значениях мы бы получили число символов 14

                     count += 100 * 5;
                     count += 1000 * 4;
                     count += 10000 * 3;
                     count += 100000 * 2;
                     count += 1000000 * 1;
                     count += 10000000 * 1;
                     count += 100000000 * 1;
                     count += 1000000000 * 1; // а при этих значениях мы бы получили число символов 11112345                      

                    /*
                    byte[] array = new byte[breader.Read];

                    breader.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
                    if (array == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("array пустой!");
                        return;

                        // декодируем байты в строку
                        string textFromFile = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);
                        textBox_String.Text = textFromFile;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    */
                    MessageBox.Show("нет");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();                   

            }
        }
     } 
 }
```

В графах ВЫЯСНИТЬ КАК, мне надо примерно понять, что именно в них надо писать? И как? С этим путаница... Вкратце, я создаю программу архиватор, который добавляет и извлекает любые файлы преобразуя в бинарный формат и наоборот.

При шифровке использовались спец символы юникода (для добавления начала и конца бинарного файла) и текст "abcdefghigklmn" Также мне говорили, что неправильно написан код в цикле, из-за чего он не видит переменную "line" в другой части кода. Переменная count - считывает количество байтов в коде.  Это все для кнопки извлечь.

В методе `Int64.TryParse(line, out digit);` он не видит line, а я не понимаю почему. Мне говорил препод, что неправильно написан код в теле цикла... А я не понимаю как...

**Обновление**

Qwerty, какая именно строка теряется? И что нужно, чтобы он в методе `Int64.TryParse(line, out digit);` увидел этот line? Куда его надо вставить или поставить??? Я вот это не могу понять...

**Обновление 2**

И да, вкратце, это дипломная работа у меня такая, а преподаватель не может с этим помочь, так как говорит, что это азы C# и это все элементарно.... А я не понимаю, как это все дописать и правильно структуру написать + еще и объяснить точно вопросы по этому. Море сайтов перерыл и ни как не могу выяснить, что мне нужно.  Вот ссылка на Kiber-forum(e) [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1430454.html)

Список литературы прочитал, и по ней и пытался сделать, но ничего не выходит. А времени осталось уже мало а тему не изменить уже. И я просто не знаю, что делать. В различных книгах искал и читал по записи текста в бинарный файл. Я могу скинуть сам исходник этой программы, как она в общем выглядит (если это как-то поможет).

Comment: Для начала, ваша проблема в том, что у кода напрочь отсутствует структура. Вследствие этого не только мы не можем понять код, а и вам это сложно. В вашем коде намешано UI, чтение данных и логика архивации. Не делайте так. Разделите код на маленькие, простые, самостоятельные части, и многие проблемы уйдут сами собой. Возможно, вам помогут ответы на [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416644/10105).

Comment: Было бы все тут все понятно - может быть смог бы лучше структуру кода сделать, а так запутался...

Comment: Для начала, поделить код на UI, доступ к файлам и обработку данных в памяти. Это лучше разнести в отдельные классы. Потом, на досуге, почитайте про MVVM или MVC (но это на будущее).

Comment: это примерно таким методом? http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level5/5_1.php

Comment: Ну, по вашей ссылке там только написано, что такое класс. Это вы и так должны знать. Если не знаете, читайте книги, без этого вообще в принципе никак.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> using (var stream = File.OpenText("some.csv"))
> {                                
>   string line = stream.ReadLine(); // следующий символ
>   while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null) // line[1], line[2]
> ```

Во-первых, не символ, а строку. Во-вторых, первая считанная строка теряется.