# Зачем нужно всегда ставить фигурные скобки: { и }?

Tags: if, синтаксис, code-style

Я не понимаю, зачем все говорят, что нужно всегда использовать `{` и `}`.
Вот, например, код:

```
if(1>2)
{
    test = true;
}
```

Зачем тут писать скобки?
Многие говорят, что для читаемости, но любой программист знает о таком написании, зачем же увеличить код?

Также лично я не понимаю зачем открытие скобки писать на новой строке, чтобы занять ещё одну лишнюю строку?

На мой взгляд это неправильно, возможно вы меня сможете в этом переубедить?

Лично мне намного быстрее и удобнее разобрать вот такой код:

```
if ($a === $b) bar();
elseif($a > $b) $foo->bar($arg1);
else BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
```

Чем:

```
if ($a === $b)
{
    bar();
} elseif ($a > $b)
{
    $foo->bar($arg1);
} else
{
    BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Вот почему люди сразу задают вопросы еще до попытки что-либо найти самостоятельно ?

Comment: Затем что используя скобки в данном случае вы обезопасите себя от глупых ошибок.

Comment: пиши как хочешь. работу найдёт лучший.

Comment: Две основные причины: для читаемости кода и во избежание глупых ошибок. Попробуйте перечитать свой код спустя несколько месяцев. Сами же в своем коде будете тупить.

Comment: А за что минусы, кстати? Нормальный вопрос.

Comment: Я вот тоже не подумав кинул минус, сейчас не могу забрать. И закрывать его не надо.

Comment: Предлагаю переоткрыть - раз есть конкретные примеры, в которых код по разному себя ведет при разной расстановке скобок -> вопрос не так уж "зависит от мнения".

Comment: кинул победно-переоткрывающий голос

Comment: Закрывать этот вопрос было в принципе бессмысленно. Да, по стандартам англ. SO это "primarily opinion-based", т.е. однозначного ответа нет и быть не может. Но тут вопросы такого типа, извините, весь топ заняли, так что тут это норма.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ответ на самом деле зависит от языка.

Некоторые языки ([javascript, I'm looking at you](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424133/10105)) практически требуют специальной расстановки скобок, в их отсутствие код может распарситься неочевидным образом.

В остальных языках-с-фигурными-скобками (C/C++/Java/C#/...) расстановка скобок — личное дело каждого, вопрос вкуса. Я лично стараюсь опустить скобки где только возможно, например, в коде

```
if (x > 0) x = -x;
```

Другим, наоборот, нравится наличие скобок, так как это позволяет коду

```
if (x > 0)
{
    x = -x;
}

if (y > 0)
{
    y = -y;
    z = x;
}
```

выглядеть однообразно.

Мой совет — пишите код так, чтобы форматирование подчёркивало вашу мысль. Например, симметрию внутренних структур кода. Это самое главное. Наличие или отсутствие скобок не сделают вас плохим программистом, отсутствие стиля вполне может.

---

Важный отдельный случай — это наличие общего стиля команды. Если во всей команде принято ставить (или не ставить) дополнительные скобки, вам придётся придерживаться общего стиля.

Answer (score 44):

Практика всегда ставить скобки избавляет вас от досадных глупых ошибок.

**Страшилка 1**. Жил-был метод с guard condition:

```
if(somethingBad())
    return;
```

В один прекрасный день вы собираетесь домой, вас просят быстренько добавить логгирование туда. Ткнули по кнопкам (может быть даже по хоткею для live template), закоммитили:

```
if(somethingBad())
    log.error("Something bad happened");
    return;
```

И ушли. А кто-то потом тратит пару часов, чтобы найти эту невзрачную ошибку.

---

**Страшилка 2**. Жил был код:

```
if (reallyRareCondition())
    handleIt();
doImportantThings();
```

Однажды джуниора попросили временно убрать обработку Очень Редкого Случая. Он смело закомментировал соответствующую строку и ушел играть в кикер с коллегами.

```
if (reallyRareCondition())
//    handleIt();
doImportantThings();
```

А потом вдруг Что-то Очень Важное перестало работать кроме редких случаев.

---

PS. Все совпадения не случайны, а действующие лица не выдуманы.

Comment: Ну ладно, насколько ж надо быть невнимательным, чтобы не заметить, куда вставляется код? Если программист _настолько_ невнимателен, он может и промахнуться и положить `log.error` после `return`. Невнимательный программист может сделать _любую_ глупость, так что здесь уж защититься не удастся.

Comment: Из такой же борьбы с невнимательностью растёт и требование не более одного `return`'а на функцию — а _вдруг_ программист затупит и не освободит ресурсы?

Comment: Внимательный/невнимательный - неважно. Все устают, все ошибаются. Если можно обезопаситься - лучше обезопаситься.

Comment: Не, «обезопаситься» — так надо перед каждым использованием указателя проверять его на 0. Проверки функциональности должны делаться юнит-тестами, и никак иначе.

Comment: Код UI, напрмер, не всегда просто покрыть тестами.

Comment: Ну, это зависит от среды разработки. Visual Studio, например, умеет [coded UI test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx).

Comment: Ну вот почему пустые строки нормально не ставить? Просто потому что скобки заставить ставить проще?

Comment: какие пустые строки? куда?

Comment: Пустые строки вокруг. Если вопрос разморозят, напишу ответом. А тут даже не знаю, как объяснеть, без форматирования-то...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Разморозили.

Comment: @VladD, написал ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424351/178988

Comment: Для любителей ставить скобки: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430885/178988 - шикарный код. return, затем 2 оператора и ещё один return. И всё в скобках. И почему же оно не работает?)))

Comment: От обеих страшилок можно защититься просто и банально: достаточно располагать однострочный код без скобок в той же строке, что и условие. И никакой джуниор не встроит и не уберет ничего лишнего.

Answer (score 11):

> Лично я не понимаю зачем открытие скобки писать на новой строке, что бы занять ещё одну лишнюю строку?

Наличие скобок и способ их расстановки это не просто вопрос стиля или личных предпочтений. Сейчас многие удивяться, но в `javascript` код в зависимости от расстановки скобок выполняется по разному. Смотрите фокус:

```js
function sample1() {
    return {
        foo: 'test'
    };
}

function sample2() {
    return
    {
        foo: 'test'
    };
}

alert(sample1()); // object
alert(sample2()); // undefined!
```

и это не баг :)

Comment: Это уже другое дело, я говорил про скобки в if

Comment: В вопросе if упоминается толкьо в контесте "например". В общем случае разница в стиле постановки скобок может привести к разному результату выполнения - я именно про это хотел сказать.

Comment: Это уже особенности языка, там и `;` в общем-то не нужна. Но ставить надобно, юные падаваны!

Comment: @TheDoctor Ставить-то надобно, но это не поможет. :)

Comment: @Discord, В данном случае - нет, знатоки поймут почему. Но в общем и целом посыл такой - некоторые языки крайне гибкие и очень многое позволяют (---как выпившая шлюха---), но это не значит что это позволение освобождает от ответственности за раздолбайство и экономию одной-двух строчек кода.

Comment: А в чем причина такого разного поведения функций?

Comment: @Cowboyserg это фича JS, Automatic Semicolon Insertion. Во втором примере строчка выполняется как `return ;` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846298/1988244

Answer (score 11):

> ```
> if(1>2)
> {
>     test = true;
> }
> ```

> Зачем тут писать скобки?

Лично я в таких случаях обычно не ставлю. Могу поставить, если дальше идёт блок else со скобками, да и то не всегда. Почти всегда ставлю в js (и джаве) - там, где принято ставить открывающую на той же строке.

> Многие говорят что для читаемости, но любой программист знает о таком написании, зачем же увеличить код?

Дело в том, что такие выражения как правило идут среди другого кода, а не сами по себе. Соответственно, скобки явно выделяют блок, который относится к условию. Например:

```
DoSmth1();
DoSomeOtherMagic();
if(x>7)
  Logger.Log(x);
DoSmth(x, 2, 12, y, temp);
DoALotOfOtherStuff(x);
```

С какой вероятностью, радактируя этот код, можно случайно неправильно внести строчку в if или закомментировать имеющуюся там? Мне тоже рассказывали про реальные случаи, что комментировали логирование и следующая команда попадала в if.

Как же пытаются решить эту проблему? Говорят, всегда ставим скобки. В таком случае получается такой код:

```
DoSmth1();
DoSomeOtherMagic();
if(x>7)
{
  Logger.Log(x);
}
DoSmth(x, 2, 12, y, temp);
DoALotOfOtherStuff(x);
```

Да, здесь уже значительно сложнее ошибиться и как-то не так поступить с этим блоком. Но написан ли этот код красиво? На мой взгляд, нет. Это по прежнему мешанина вызовов методов и проверки условия. Причём, блок кода мы выделили, но таким образом мы ещё и отдалили вызываемый метод от условия.

А вот как бы я отформатировал этот же код:

```
DoSmth1();
DoSomeOtherMagic();

if(x>7)
  Logger.Log(x);

DoSmth(x, 2, 12, y, temp);
DoALotOfOtherStuff(x);
```

Здесь нет скобок, но я потратил те же две строки, чтобы сделать вертикальные отступы. При редактировании такого кода, по сравнению с первым, гораздо сложнее ошибиться при его изменении, блок с условием заметно отделяется от остального кода, а содержимое блока идёт рядом с условием, а не отодвигается от него при помощи скобок.

> зачем все говорят что нужно всегда использовать { и }

Потому что это проще сказать. Сказать, "пишите код в читаемом виде" - это как ничего не сказать - автор почти всегда скажет, что его код читаемый. А обговаривать все условия - это сложно. Например, я всегда ставлю скобки, если есть вторая строка - даже если она комментарий.

Сейчас почти для всех языков IDE имеют автоформатирование. Для чего? Для того ли, чтобы было быстрее писать код? Или всё-таки для того, чтобы более или менее читаемый код мог писать кто угодно? Почему чем язык распространённее (и, в некоторой мере, проще), тем строже правила автоформатирования? Посмотрим на дефаултные настройки в Visual Studio. Для C++ (если я не ошибаюсь) нет автоматического добавления пробелов вокруг бинарных операторов. В C# есть. В VB.NET принудительное жёсткое форматирование отступов при уходе со строки. Случайность ли это? Вот мне кажется, что вряд ли.

Почему предлагается всегда ставить пробелы у бинарных операторов? Какой вариант читаемее `y = a*x*x + b*x + c;` или `y = a * x * x + b * x + c;`? На мой взгляд первый. Тогда зачем? Да чтобы защититься от такого: `y=a*x*x+b*x+c;`.

Так же и со скобками - это лёгкий путь предотвратить ошибки. Но лёгкий - не значит лучший. В IDE всё больше фич автоформатирования (которые, кстати, иногда бесят, когда ты хочешь внести изменение в одну строчку, а файл отформатирован не под текущий профиль), но вот отступы в виде пустых строк сами делаться не умеют. Да и в стайл-гайдах очень редко это прописывается. Точнее, часто для css и подобных, возможно ещё, отступы между функциями, но больше ничего не упоминается. Выравнивание кода в столбцы (про которое тоже недавно был вопрос) тоже упоминается крайне редко.

Ну и ещё примерчик. Что лучше?

```
if(user.HasRole("Admin"))
{
  return SomeAdminData();
}
if(user.HasRole("Moderator"))
{
  return SomeModeratorData();
}
if(user.HasRole("User"))
{
  return SomeData();
}
return SomeAnonimousData();
```

или всё-таки

```
if(user.HasRole("Admin"))
  return SomeAdminData();

if(user.HasRole("Moderator"))
  return SomeModeratorData();

if(user.HasRole("User"))
  return SomeData();

return SomeAnonimousData();
```

но мне бы как-то не хотелось увидеть

```
if(user.HasRole("Admin"))
  return SomeAdminData();
if(user.HasRole("Moderator"))
  return SomeModeratorData();
if(user.HasRole("User"))
  return SomeData();
return SomeAnonimousData();
```

потому что тут сложно зацепиться глазами за блоки.

Кстати, как вариант, тут может быть

```
if(user.HasRole("Admin"))       return SomeAdminData();
if(user.HasRole("Moderator"))   return SomeModeratorData();
if(user.HasRole("User"))        return SomeData();
               /*Anonimous*/    return SomeAnonimousData();
```

Но с этим подходом надо быть осторожным и использовать только тогда, когда это имеет смысл.

Кстати, с этим вариантом могут быть проблемы с автоформатированием в IDE. Потому что я бы однозначно не хотел увидеть

```
if(user.HasRole("Admin")) return SomeAdminData();
if(user.HasRole("Moderator")) return SomeModeratorData();
if(user.HasRole("User")) return SomeData();
/*Anonimous*/ return SomeAnonimousData();
```

такой вариант вообще нечитаемый.

> Так же лично я не понимаю зачем открытие скобки писать на новой строке

Скобки на новой строке удобны тем, что видно, к какому блоку они относятся.

Следующий код читаем. Он читаем даже если скобки по какой-то причине съедут.

```
for(q=0; q<n; ++q)
  for(w=0; w<m; ++w)
    if(q!=w)
      {
      for(e=0; e<k; ++e)
        if(a[q][e]==a[w][e])
          DoSmth(q, w, e);

      b[q][e] += a[q][k] - a[w][k];
      }
```

А как насчёт варианта со скобкой на той же строке? А если по какой-то причине скобка окажется не там где надо?

```
for(q=0; q<n; ++q)
  for(w=0; w<m; ++w)
    if(q!=w) {
      for(e=0; e<k; ++e)
        if(a[q][e]==a[w][e])
          DoSmth(q, w, e);

      b[q][e] += a[q][k] - a[w][k];
      }
```

Раньше в VS были проблемы с автоформатирование отступов в Си++, если нет скобок. Кстати, это ещё одна возможная причина, почему скобки надо ставить.

В языках, где скобки расставляются подобным образом (открывающая на той же строке), я всегда ставлю скобки... И скобки, и отступы, если непонятно.

Например, вот что станет с кодом выше, если в коде в табами (у просматривающего в 2 пробела) добавили 2 строки (и скобки) с отступами в 4 пробела:

```
for(q=0; q<n; ++q)
  for(w=0; w<m; ++w)
    if(q!=w)
            {
      for(e=0; e<k; ++e)
        if(a[q][e]==a[w][e])
          DoSmth(q, w, e);

            b[q][e] += a[q][k] - a[w][k];
            }
```

Благодаря пустой строке после вложенных конструкций, первый код легко читается даже в таком не слишком приглядном виде. А теперь посмотрим на второй вариант:

```
for(q=0; q<n; ++q)
  for(w=0; w<m; ++w)
    if(q!=w) {
      for(e=0; e<k; ++e)
        if(a[q][e]==a[w][e])
          DoSmth(q, w, e);

            b[q][e] += a[q][k] - a[w][k];
            }
```

И ни одной хорошей мысли при взгляде на это чудо...

> чтобы занять ещё одну лишнюю строку?

Занятые строки должны быть далеко не на первом месте. Так можно и весь код в одну строку написать. Но вот нужно ли?

Куда важнее общая читаемость кода. Надо для этого занять лишнюю строку, да хоть 5 - пусть будут. Есть 20 однотипных вызовов 4 методов? Отформатировать столбиками (получится 20 строк) и пофиг, что строки длинные и в них несколько операторов. Кстати, вариант с форматирование столбиками - это практически единственный случай, где я допускаю наличие нескольких операторов в строке.

> Лично мне намного быстрее и удобнее разобрать вот такой код:
>
> ```
> if ($a === $b) bar();
> elseif($a > $b) $foo->bar($arg1);
> else BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
> ```

Во-первых, если понадобится просматривать структуру кода, то это не слишком удобно читать. В смысле, если ты детально просматриваешь метод и читаешь полностью каждую строку, то всё хорошо. Но если ты просто бегло смотришь код, пытаясь понять, где и что используется, то совмещение условия с вызываемым методом может оказаться неудобным.

Во-вторых, здесь нельзя поставить breakpoint на вызов метода. Так что отладке может помешать.

Сам использую запись в одну строку только иногда в VB, где есть синтаксис однострочного if.

> Чем:
>
> ```
> if ($a === $b)
> {
>     bar();
> } elseif ($a > $b)
> {
>     $foo->bar($arg1);
> } else
> {
>     BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
> }
> ```

А вот такой стиль я виду впервые. Видел такое:

```
if ($a === $b)
{
    bar();
}
elseif ($a > $b)
{
    $foo->bar($arg1);
}
else
{
    BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
}
```

такое

```
if ($a === $b) {
    bar();
}
elseif ($a > $b) {
    $foo->bar($arg1);
}
else {
    BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
}
```

и такое

```
if ($a === $b) {
    bar();
} elseif ($a > $b) {
    $foo->bar($arg1);
} else {
    BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
}
```

Но вот вариант, когда открывающаяся скобка на отдельной строке, а закрывающаяся перед else - это что-то странное. Тоже не понимаю, зачем.

Comment: Спасибо! Хороший ответ, кстати.

Comment: Круто написал, я аж зачитался )

Answer (score 9):

Включаем истерику

> Так же лично я не понимаю зачем открытие скобки писать на новой строке, что бы занять ещё одну лишнюю строку?

БОЖЕЧКИ БОЖЕЧКИ ЛИШНЯЯ СТРОКА ЗАЙМЕТСЯ
ЭТО ЖЕ ЕЩЕ НЕСКОЛЬКО БАЙТ ПО СЕТИ ПЕРЕДАВАТЬ
ПОЖАЛУЙ, НЕ БУДУ СТАВИТЬ ЭТУ СКОБКУ

> Многие говорят что для читаемости, но любой программист знает о таком написании, зачем же увеличить код?

ЛЮБОЙ ПРОГРАММИСТ ЗНАЕТ, ЧТО МОЖНО НАПИСАТЬ КОД В ОДНУ СТРОЧКУ, А ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ МОГУТ БЫТЬ И В ОДИН СИМВОЛ

```
if($a===$b)bar();elseif($a>$b)$f->b($arg1);else Bz::br($a2,$3);
```

МММММ
КАКАЯ ВКУСНАЯ ЭКОНОМИЯ БАЙТОВ

Если серьезно, то разве вы хоть что-то делаете лучше, избавляясь от лишних пробелов и скобок? Вы же вообще ничего не экономите, ну совсем ничего. Про страшилки и общепринятый PSR уже рассказали.

Comment: Дело не в экономии ,а в удобном читаемости кода

Comment: @Mr_Epic на самом деле на новой строке действительно не нужно, только в классах-функциях-методах. Более читаемый - тот стиль, который используется в абсолютном большинстве ПО, и это PSR c рассатновкой скобок.

Answer (score 8):

> зачем писать скобки.

это от языка программирования зависит. В с/с++ скобки можно не писать, если дальше будет один оператор. А в от в перл в подобной конструкции скобки нужно писать (если только не инфиксный оператор), потому что там такой синтаксис.

Но некоторые считают, что писать нужно в любом случае - так как в будущем может появится ещё одна строка внутри if и придется дописывать скобки.

> Так же лично я не понимаю зачем открытие скобки писать на новой строке, что бы занять ещё одну лишнюю строку?

тут нужно отталкиваться от стандартов, принятых в Вашей компании или личных предпочтений (для своего кода).

> На мой взгляд это неправильно, возможно вы меня сможете в этом переубедить?

на мой взгляд, правильнее писать указанный код так:

```
if ($a === $b) {
    bar();
} elseif ($a > $b) {
    $foo->bar($arg1);
} else {
    BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
}
```

А Ваши два варианта не пройдут кодревью. Но зачем мне Вас переубеждать. Пока Вы пишете код для себя - пишите как хотите, хоть по слову на строку. А вот когда пишете код для компании - тут нужно следовать правилам. Зарплата  может быть хорошим инструментом переубеждения.

Answer (score 4):

Немного опоздал на вечеринку, но все равно зайду.

ТС смотри глубже, зачем вообще нужны `if`, `else`, эти дурацкие переводы строк, точки с запятой фигурные скобки и знаки доллара если есть старый добрый тренарный условный оператор.

```
(a==b) ? c() : (a>b) ? d.c(f) : e.c(g,h);
```

Comment: В таком варианте очень сложно разобрать код

Comment: Круглые скобки у условий не к месту.

Answer (score 3):

Ну и в завершение нашего цирка, вот вам на ночь очень мудрый пример обращения со скобками. Когда этот код был Явой. [доказательство](http://govnokod.ru/17680)

```
public class Permuter                            {
private static void permute(int n, char[] a)     {
    if (n == 0)                                  {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(a))    ;}
    else                                         {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)             {
            permute(n-1, a)                      ;
            swap(a, n % 2 == 0 ? i : 0, n)       ;}}}
private static void swap(char[] a, int i, int j) {
    char saved = a[i]                            ;
    a[i] = a[j]                                  ;
    a[j] = saved                                 ;}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть стандарты кода, например [PSR](http://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/#_PSR-2). Если предыдущий программист придерживался стандартов, то вы будете легче и быстрее читать написанный им код. Почему легче и быстрее? Потому что ваш мозг - это тот же компьютер. В случае обработки стандартных операций (шаблонов) затрачивается меньше ресурсов на их обработку.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие программисты-зануды, которые пользуются отладкой кода в ide.  И если Вы хотите чтобы они каждый раз, когда захотят поставить точку остановы, вспоминали Вас, то пишите в одну строчку и икота с красными ушами Вам обеспечена!

Comment: Ну, лично я, открывая любой чужой исходник в IDE, первым делом жму Ctrl+Shift+F. И только потом уже смотрю в код. Конечно, скобки оно само не проставит, но форматирование для всех используемых языков настроено до мельчайших деталей.

Comment: Проблем нет, Visual Studio умеет ставить breakpoint на часть строки. Пользуйтесь нормальными IDE!

Comment: Ну и кроме того, если скобок нет, но код расположен на новой строке, то breakpoint поставится без проблем в чём угодно.

Comment: @klopp, у применения автоформатирования перед просмотром кода тоже есть недостатки. Во-первых, что-то могло быть отформатировано хорошо, а после автоформатирования стать плохо - особенно это касается столбцового форматирования. Во-вторых, например, в html автоформатирование может испортить страницу (я про пробелы между inline-block). И ещё, если это закоммитить, то ты станешь считаться автором чужих строк.

Comment: @Qwertiy: С другой стороны, коммит без ручного просмотра диффа — грубая халатность.

Comment: На проекте, где я мог спокойно переформатировать код, я это без проблем делал. А в SVN для просмотра дифов использовался WinMerge, где в настройках было выставлено игнорирование пробелов, так что он бы даже не показал, что там где-то пробелы на табуляции поменялись, хотя перед коммитом изменения я смотрел.

Comment: Что такое winmerge я не знаю, использую либо tkdiff, либо meld, либо встроенный в eclipse дифф. Само собой, во всех случаях пробелы игнорируются. Но в любом случае лучше немного поправить после предварительного автоформатирования, чем полностью всё перелопачивать руками (особенно если оно в стиле как в посте). BTW, сишный код после indent, astyle или bcpp можно ещё поковырять. А вот перловый после заботливо настроенного perltidy лет за 10 желание поправить возникало хорошо если раза 3-4...

Answer (score 2):

Если вам не нравятся скобки, возможно вам стоит выбрать в качестве языка Python. Там с вами полностью солидарны :)

```
if a == b:
    print('a == b')
elif c == d:
    print('c == d')
else
    print(':)')
```

Comment: Дело не в том нравятся они мне или нет, а в том что бы не писать их, где не нужно

Answer (score 1):

> Зачем тут писать скобки?

На этот вопрос уже дан хороший [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424128/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8/424135#424135).

> Так же лично я не понимаю зачем открытие скобки писать на новой
>   строке, что бы занять ещё одну лишнюю строку?

1. Зачем писать открытие скобки на новой строке?

Сейчас я пишу открытие скобки на новой строке, потому что это соответствует выбранному на данный момент стилю написания и, следовательно, повышает читабельность кода. Тема о преимуществах и недостатках тех или иных стилей слишком обширна и спорна, чтобы затрагивать ее здесь.

2. Зачем писать открытие скобки на той же строке?

Долгое время я писал открытие скобки на той же строке, потому что так **безопаснее**. Приходится иногда видеть такие ошибки (и сам я грешен был):

```
if(1>2);
{
    test = true;
}
```

Заканчивать строку точкой с запятой настолько естественно в C/C++, что иногда это делается на бессознательном уровне. Однако, если ставить открытие скобки на новой строке, то появляются строки, которые **нельзя** закрывать точкой с запятой, потому что это может привести к трудно отлавливаемой логической ошибке. Чтобы такие строки не появлялись, лучше писать так:

```
if(1>2) {;
    test = true;
}
```

Тогда даже лишняя точка с запятой не приведет к ошибке. Да она скорее всего даже не появится, потому что после открывающей скобки бессознательного желания ставить точку с запятой нет. По крайней мере мне такой код видеть не приходилось.

P.S. Те, кто не брезгует макросами, могут сочетать открытие скобки на новой строке и безопасность. Например так:

```
#define FOR_S( ... ) for( __VA_ARGS__ ) {
#define END_FOR_S }

#define IF_S( ... ) if( __VA_ARGS__ ) {
#define END_IF_S }
#define ELSE_S } else {
#define ELSE_IF_S } else IF_S

#define WHILE_S( ... ) while( __VA_ARGS__ ) {
#define END_WHILE_S }
```

Тогда код с макросами будет выглядеть так:

```
IF_S( toWorkWithA );
{
    makeAInput();
    sendtoA();
}
END_IF_S;
```

Лишняя точка с запятой не приведет к ошибке.

Однако: а) использование макросов тоже **не безопасно**, б) для кого-то замена ключевых слов на макросы может влиять на читабельность кода в худшую сторону.