# Запрет прокрутки на время анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animation, fullpage

Я задал вопрос по плагину на GitHub'е. Вот что мне ответили:

> To disable it, you return false. Otherwise it will scroll normally. 
>   You might want to use javascript callbacks to return true if you make some action, your code doesn´t make sense with two returns.
>
> You'd better ask for javascript question in other place such as
>   stackoverflow.com

То, что здесь написано, я понял так: *Чтобы отключить, возвратите false. В противном случае всё будет прокручиваться нормально* (плагин для прокрутки). Мой код с двумя `return` - это бред. Нужно вернуть `true` как-то по-особенному, используя обратные вызовы для `return: true`.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var $info_panel = $('.info_panel');
    var $el2 = $('.el2');
    var $el3 = $('.el3');
    $('.el1').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $info_panel.toggleClass('slide_panel');
        $el2.toggleClass('slide_content');
        $el3.toggleClass('slide_content');
    });
    $('.el3').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
    });
})
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        css3: true,
        loopBottom: true,
        onLeave(index, nextIndex, direction) {
            var $info_panel = $('.info_panel');
            var $el2 = $('.el2');
            if (index == 1) {
                $info_panel.removeClass('slide_panel');
                $el2.removeClass('slide_content');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.info_panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: 22.5vw;
    background-color: #565656;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    right: -22.5vw;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: right .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: right .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: right .3s linear;
    -o-transition: right .3s linear;
    transition: right .3s linear;
}
#show_info_panel {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    display:block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    top: -5px;
}
.slide_panel {
    right: 0;
}
.slide_content {
    right: 8.5vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="info_panel">
            <span class="i">i</span>
        </div>
        <div class="el1">
            <span id="show_info_panel">i</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="el2">
                <p class="text">Aleshkalavrushka.ml – только не надо путать подлинный продукт с тем, что продается в магазинах. Не смотри долго на Aleshkalavrushka.ml, а не то Aleshkalavrushka.ml взглянет на тебя. Вообще, думаю, что Aleshkalavrushka.ml – это аллегория. Вспоминаются стихи: «Идем по небесному телу Земля из точки рождения «А» в точку «Aleshkalavrushka.ml». *** Блуждаем по свету во тьме, пока нас не сцапает Aleshkalavrushka.ml. *** Хоть кажется, что это небыль, но по Земле ведет нас Aleshkalavrushka.ml». «Aleshkalavrushka.ml – не тот, кто в застолье крут, И когда за здоровье пьют, Aleshkalavrushka.ml не станет тебе кричать: «Пей до дна!», Aleshkalavrushka.ml почувствует, что тебе стало холодно на Земле, И согреет своим теплом без вина»... Тот, кто действительно имеет Aleshkalavrushka.ml, не боится признать своих ошибок. Где тебя рады видеть всегда? Там, где Aleshkalavrushka.ml. Мы всегда ждем Aleshkalavrushka.ml, и, в глубине души, надеемся, что с каждым разом Aleshkalavrushka.ml будет все лучше и лучше. Не бойтесь признаться в этом. Японские инженеры решили, что самой страшной болезнью будущего будет одиночество. Поэтому они встроили Aleshkalavrushka.ml в приборную доску нового автомобиля. Aleshkalavrushka.ml будет распознавать гримасы водителя и рассказывать ему анекдоты, чтобы поднять настроение. Aleshkalavrushka.ml становится не только повседневностью, но и принимается обществом и даже поощряется. А вот «Lm akhsurvalakhsela» – это Aleshkalavrushka.ml наоборот.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="el3">
                <span class="down">▼</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <p class="text">Глянь - из дядиной гладильни,
            <br>вожделенный и взрывной,
            <br>выбегает эпилептик
            <br>с синтетической серьгой!
            <br>
            <br>Королество заорало,
            <br>замусолилась слеза,
            <br>дуло злобно заскользило,
            <br>и растрогалась хамса...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Пример в JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LuvLsLq/).

Подытожим. Что же мне надо? Итак, ход работы: `false` - авто скролинг выключен, `true` (стоит по умолчанию) - включён.

`$info_panel.removeClass('slide_panel');` - анимация 1.
`$el2.removeClass('slide_content');` - анимация 2.

Нужно чтобы автоскроллинг был выключен на время проигрывания анимация. После окончания анимации автоскролинг должен быть включён. Так, как написал я, не работает. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Думаю, после этой моей правки вопрос уже можно считать правильно оформленным. Насчет запрета скролла на время анимации сейчас подумаю. Думаю, "топорное" решение вполне устроит?

Comment: Конечно. Мне бы хоть как-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея заключается в использовании флага `menuIsAnimated`, который на время анимации (для наглядности в примере взято 2 секунды) `menuAnimationTimeMS` блокирует пролистывание страницы, и в повторном вызове пролистывания `$.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown()` при закрытии меню из `onLeave`.

"Некрасивым" моментом в коде является то, что значение `menuAnimationTimeMS` жестко задано константой. По идее, брать его нужно из CSS значения `transition`, однако это не так просто, поэтому решил не переусложнять пример.

Изменённый JS:

```
$(function()
{
    var $info_panel = $('.info_panel');
    var $el2 = $('.el2');
    var $el3 = $('.el3');

    var menuAnimationTimeMS = 2000;
    var menuIsAnimated = false;

    $('.el1').on("click", function()
    {
        animateMenu(false);
        return false;
    });

    $el3.on("click", function()
    {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
        return false;
    });

    function animateMenu(toScrollOnFinish)
    {
        menuIsAnimated = true;
        $info_panel.toggleClass('slide_panel');
        $el2.toggleClass('slide_content');
        $el3.toggleClass('slide_content');
        var onFinish = function()
        {
            menuIsAnimated = false;
            if (toScrollOnFinish)
            {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
            }
        };
        setTimeout(onFinish, menuAnimationTimeMS);
    }

    $('#fullpage').fullpage(
    {
        css3: true,
        loopBottom: true,
        onLeave: function()
        {
            if (!menuIsAnimated && $info_panel.hasClass('slide_panel'))
            {
                animateMenu(true);
                return false;
            }
            return !menuIsAnimated;
        }
    });
});
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LuvLsLq/3/).

[Альтернативная версия](http://jsfiddle.net/8LuvLsLq/2/) с возможностью прервать открытие меню из `onLeave`.