# В чем разница цикла/условия с фигурными скобками без?

Tags: c++, циклы, предложения

```
int num = 5;

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    cout << i; 
}

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cout << i;
```

Comment: В данном случае разницы нет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Закрывающие, какие подробности вопроса вы хотите уточнить? о_О

Answer (score 5):

Нет никакой разницы.

Согласно стандарту C++ (6.5 Iteration statements)

> 2 The substatement in an iteration-statement implicitly defines a
>   block scope (3.3) which is entered and exited each time through the
>   loop. If the substatement in an iteration-statement is a single
>   statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten
>   to be a compound-statement containing the original statement. [
>   Example:

```
while (--x >= 0)
    int i;
```

can be equivalently rewritten as

```
while (--x >= 0) {
    int i;
}
```

То есть одиночное предложение в for-предложении рассматривается как будто бы оно является составным предложением, то есть имеет блочную область определения.

Однако в C эти предложения из примера из стандарта C++ не эквивалентны. В C объявление не является предложением. Поэтому в C вы не можете записать

```
while (--x >= 0)
    int i;
```

Компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, так как.

```
    int i;
```

не является предложением. Это объявление.

Но вы можете записать

```
while (--x >= 0) {
    int i;
}
```

так как объявления можно помещать в кодовый блок.

В этом состоит одно из различий C++  и C.

Еще один наглядный пример того, как это различие сказывается на программах, написанных на C++  и C, указан [в этой теме](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000050-000-0-0-1412969191) на моем персональном форуме.

Answer (score 5):

Если не использовать фигурные скобки для отделения блока можно получить, ошибку при добавлении операторов

```
int i = 6;
while(i--)
   do_some(i);
   do_some_to(i); //вызов только после выполнения цикла, а не в цикле как, возможно, преполагалось
```

Кроме того блоком можно управлять областью видимости переменной

```
int i = 6;
while(i--){
    const auto tmp_var = do_some(i);
    do_some_to(tmp_var);
}
```

Общая рекомендация, для сокращения ошибок и читабельности кода всегда использовать {}. Избегать конструкций в одну строку вида:

```
for(int = 0;i<10; i++) do_some(i);
```

Comment: Здесь я полностью соглашусь с sitev_ru, что нет никакой необходимости использовать фигурные скобки в этом for предложении for(int = 0;i<10; i++) do_some(i);, и без фигурных скобок в одну строчку оно выглядит более читабельным как одно предложение языка.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , например, в гугл считают иначе: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Loops_and_Switch_Statements

Comment: @Croessmah И что из того? А в другой фирме другие низко-квалифицированные программисты будут считать по-другому.  При этом имейте в виду, что внутри-фирменный стиль - это что-то среднее, что гребет все под одну гребенку. То есть это усредниловка.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Макконнелл тоже писал, что избегает такого стиля. Например, он пишет, что при использовании построчного отладчика, сие будет рассматриваться как одно целое, что не есть хорошо. Также нарушается структура вложенности кода и это тоже не айс. И знаете, я с ним полностью согласен. Лично мне категорически не нравится стиль в одну строчку. Конечно, это спор о вкусе и цвете, выбранных в конторе.

Comment: @Croessmah Вот и хорошо, что такое предложение будет рассматриваться в отладчике как одно целое! Там нечего делить на составляющие. Например, вы можете написать два предложения: for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' '; std::cout << std::endl; Либо вставить фигурные скобки и из простого цикла сделать составное предложение там, где оно совершенно не нужно. Все эти книжки, а также стили, устанавливаемые на фирмах, рассчитаны на начинающих программистов, которые еще не имеют опыта, не имеют вкуса, не имеют понимания, а потому им рекомендовано просто копировать то, что другие говорят.

Comment: @Croessmah Я вам приведу характерный пример такого бездумного идолопоклонения. Многие советуют начинающим программистам читать косноязычего Страуструпа по той причине, что Страуструп - основатель языка C++. И тем самым делают плохую услугу начинающим программистам, так как эффект от прочтения книги Страуструпа начинающим программистом обычно близок к нулю, а время тратиться очень много, так как из-за косноязычия книги Страуструпа обычно очень толстые.. .

Comment: @VladfromMoscow никто идолам не поклоняется. Я был против такого стиля категорически еще до прочтения "умных" книг. Дальнейший спор о этом, думаю, не имеет смысла. А на счет книги Страуструпа согласен - новичкам оно не нужно, имеет смысл почитать, когда уже есть багаж знаний, иначе эффект может быть не только нулевым, но и вовсе отрицательным.

Answer (score 1):

Занимает 4 строчки:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    cout << i; 
}
```

Занимает одну строчку:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) cout << i;
```

Я, обычно, не слушаю всякие рекомендации, что пиши обязательно фигурные скобки. Читабельность программного кода возрастает, если записано в одну строчку. Рекомендую 2-й вариант!

Comment: Вы - крутой перец!:) Особенно мне понравилось, что  этот блок for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    cout << i; 
} занимает 4 строчки.:) Кстати сказать его точно также можно переписать в одну строчку, сохранив фигурные скобки. Они этому не препятствуют.:)

Comment: Скобки же мешают... Ещё помню писал на паскале, так там вообще begin end

Answer (score 1):

Разницы нет, а скобки обсуждаются в другой теме:
[Объясните мне пожалуйста, зачем нужно всегда ставить { и }](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424128/178988)
И [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424351/178988) там.