# Oтсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция pow, соответствующие списку аргументов

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пишу программу на языке C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "12.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
void main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double x, y, b, u;
    cout << "Введите x,y\n";
    cin >> x >> y;
    b = pow(x, 2.)*y;
    if (b <= 0) 
        u = tan(x);
    else if (b >= 15)
         u = fabs(pow(x,exp(1.)) - y);
    else 
        u = x*pow(sin,3.)*x;
    cout << "Исходные данные\n";
    cout << "x=" << x << "y=" << y << "\n";
    cout << "Промежуточный результат\n";
    cout << "b=" << b << "\n";
    cout << "Окончательный результат\n";
    cout << "u=" << u << "\n";
}
```

Но в строке `else u = x*pow(sin,3.)*x;` выдает две ошибки:
Первая:

> Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция pow, соответствующие
>   списку аргументов, типы аргументов (`<unknown-type>, double`)

Вторая:

> Не удается определить экземпляр перегруженная функция sin,
>   использование которого предполагается

Как их исправить?

Comment: А что вы хотите от sin и от pow в этой строке? Вы передаете в функцию x^y в качестве одного из чисел что-то, что числом не является.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, примите за привычку форматировать свой код. Пусть в данной ситуации вам это не сильно поможет, но в будущем вы сможете избежать множества досадных ошибок.

Во-вторых, в строке, в которой ошибка вы в качестве аргумента функции `pow` используете *функцию* `sin`. Скорее всего, вы имели ввиду что-то вроде `else u = x*pow(sin(x),3.)*x;`, но опечатались.

И ещё: очень рекомендую брать код веток `if/else/for/while` в фигурные скобки, даже если там всего одна строка. Сам множество раз сталкивался с ситуациями, когда в такие ветки дописывалась вторая строка, а скобки не ставились, что вело к весьма неприятным ошибкам.

Comment: [Про скобки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424351/178988)

Comment: К советам можно еще добавить: не пользуйтесь русификатором в vs. Текст ошибки _"в оригинале"_ расширит аудиторию, которая сможет помочь Вам ее решить.