# Как записать это "arr = []; ⏎ arr.push(smtn);" в одну строку?

Tags: javascript, lambda

Есть такой небольшой кусочек кода:

```
if (Rect.__instances__) {
  Rect.__instances__.push(this);
} else {
  Rect.__instances__ = [];
  Rect.__instances__ = [].push(this);
}
```

Суть: если у класса есть свойство `__instances__`, то пихаем в него `this`. Если нет, то сначала инициализируем `__instances__` пустым массивом, а после этого пихаем в него `this`.

Нужно записать это условие в одну строку вида:

```
Rect.__instances__ ? Rect.__instances__.push(this) : Rect.__instances__ = [].push(this);
```

Но этот код вместо того, чтобы вернуть массив со значением `this` внутри, просто возвращает единицу.

Тогда я попробовал сделать так:

```
Rect.__instances__ ? Rect.__instances__.push(this) : Rect.__instances__ = (() => {return []}).push(this);
```

На что мне выдало ошибку вида:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).push is not a function

Пробовал еще и так:

```
Rect.__instances__ ? Rect.__instances__.push(this) : Rect.__instances__ = (() => {new Array()}).push(this);
```

Ошибка та же.

Теперь прошу помощи здесь.
Кстати, если кто-то понял, что делает этот код и для того, что я пишу есть решение получше, вроде методов стандартной библиотеки, то такой подход тоже сгодится :)

P.S. Я добавил к вопросу тег `lambda`, потому что здесь, вроде как именно про это речь и идет. Дело в том, что лямбды в JavaScript'е я гуглил, и в ответ мне выдавало только инфу, связанную со стрелочными ф-ми. Поэтому рискнул предположить, что, поскольку дело тут, скорее всего, именно в стрелочной функции, то и тег "лямбда" сюда подходит.

Comment: но зачем переписывать код в одну строку???

Comment: @Grundy некрасиво он выглядит. Люблю симметрию :D Раз уж на то пошло, то не мог я просто оставить одну строчку в if и 2 в else. А когда в одну - вообще идеально. И да, про читабельность я в курсе :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбирай. Вроде последний вариант хороший.

```
if (Rect.__instances__) {
  Rect.__instances__.push(this);
} else {
  Rect.__instances__ = [this];
}
```

```
Rect.__instances__ ? Rect.__instances__.push(this) : (Rect.__instances__ = [this]);
```

```
if (!Rect.__instances__) {
  Rect.__instances__ = [];
}

Rect.__instances__.push(this);
```

```
(Rect.__instances__ = Rect.__instances__ || []).push(this);
```

Comment: Да, последний интересный. Хотелось бы узнать, для чего во втором примере в else-statement скобки?

Comment: @smellyshovel, для того же, для чего и в if? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424351/178988

Comment: Но ведь можно было записать так? `Rect.__instances__ ? Rect.__instances__.push(this) : Rect.__instances__ = [this];`

Comment: @smellyshovel, ой. Я про первый подумал. Во втором - думал, что из-за из-за приоритетов операций, но ты прав, они там не нужны в js. Хм.. [И не только в js](http://ideone.com/E3EV8z). Просто очень редко присваивание попадает в это место. А на грабли с запятой я уже наступал))

Comment: Тогда ясно. В общем, первый и третий варианты не подходят однозначно, так как условие стояло в том, чтобы записать в одну строку. Но за четвертый вариант само собой отмечу решением. Очень уж понравилось :) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
(Rect.__instances__ = []).push(this);
```

или

```
Rect.__instances__ = [this];
```

а `push` возвращает новую длину массива, поэтому Вы и наблюдали единицу в первоначальном варианте кода.

Comment: Как обычно. До самого простого не додумался. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Rect={};

if (Rect.__instances__) {
  Rect.__instances__.push("1111");
} else {
  Rect.__instances__ = new Array("1111");
}
console.log(Rect)
```

Comment: Здесь тоже все как надо, благодарю, решение, по идее, аналогичное тому, что выше. Но я слышал, что там, где массив можно объявить литералом, там его при помощи конструктора лучше не объявлять.

Comment: Только `new Array` и не хватало.