# Когда нужно использовать `{` в операторе `if`?

Tags: javascript, if

Пример , в 1 случае используется , а во 2 - нет

```
if (inputField.value.length == 0) {
  if (helpText != null) 
    helpText.innerHTML = "Please enter a value.";
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Всегда. *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: А отступы в примере сделаны именно такими специально, чтобы запутать?

Comment: @0xdb, давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80441/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-0xdb).

Comment: @Yaant вроде нормальные отступы, не вижу проблемы

Comment: Ну, вон в чате по ссылке в соседнем комментарии как раз обсуждали эти самые отступы.

Comment: @Yaant так это дебилизм, разве это имеет значение какое кол-во отступов, они тратят ещё на это время, ебанутые

Comment: Не скажите, хорошо отформатированный код воспринимается в разы быстрее и легче. Это если даже не вспоминать о языках, где отступы — это часть синтаксиса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если оператор должен охватывать одно утверждение то `{}` не обязательно в противном случае обязательно. Вы можете использовать кривые скобки для любого оператора `if`.

Comment: "кривые" - это руки, скобки - "фигурные"

Comment: @Igor Ваш комментарий нравится людям куда больше, чем, собственно, ответ, к которому Вы его оставили хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Согласен. Хотя я несколько озадачен тем, что за комментарий проголосовало только десять человек из двадцати семи зашедших.

Answer (score 2):

Фигурными скобками в js обозначается блок кода. Оператор `if` создаёт условие, при котором этот блок кода выполнится.
Оператор `if` также можно использовать как условие для одиночного действия, также как и блок кода можно создать отдельно от условия.

Answer (score 2):

## Скобки у `if` обязательно ставить если

### Внутри несколько операторов

```
if (smth) {
  doSmth1();
  doSmth2();
}
```

### К этому `if` есть `else`, а внутри находится другой `if` без `else`

```
if (smth1) {
  if (smth2)
    doSmth12();
} else
  doOther();
```

потому что без скобок `else` будет относиться к ближайшему `if`:

```
if (smth1)
  if (smth2)
    doSmth12();
  else
    doSmth1();
```

```
if (smth1)
  if (smth2)
    doSmth12();
  else
    doSmth1();
else
  doOther();
```

## Остальные случаи

В остальных случаях `if` состоит из того, что считается одним оператором и не вызывает проблем с другими конструкциями, поэтому скобки необязательны.

---

Однако, скобки не только являются частью синтаксиса, но и играют стилистическую роль и влияют на читаемость кода. По этому моменту советую прочитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424351/178988.

Answer (score 0):

Как правило, фигурные скобки в условиях используются тогда, когда код состоит из более чем одной строки. Так код становится более читаемым.

Скобки можно и не писать, когда код состоит из одной короткой строки. Однако, очень часто на практике фигурные скобки используют всегда, независимо от количества и размера строк кода.

Пример хорошего кода:

```
if (n > 0) {
  // первая строка кода
  // вторая строка кода
  // ...
}

if (n > 0) // одна короткая строка кода

if (n > 0) {
  // одна строка кода
}
```

Пример плохого кода:

```
// фигурные скобки не имеют смысла
if (n > 0) { alert (n) }
```