# Обязательно ли использовать else?

Tags: java, jvm

Сегодня был на собеседовании по Java и завалился на операторе `if`.
Задача была в том, чтобы написать метод, который возвращает второе по величине число из входного массива. Завалился на операторе `if` при проверке данных. Моя реализация была такой:

```
public int getSecondMaxNumber(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    // далее логика получения второго макс. числа
}
```

К моему великому удивлению, оказалось, что я допустил грубейшую ошибку. Логику программы следует заключать в блок `else`, то есть так:

```
public int getSecondMaxNumber(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else {
        // именно здесь логика получения второго макс. числа
    }
}
```

Зачем весь остальной код писать в блоке `else`, если при генерировании исключения поток выполнения этого метода прервется?

Аналогично, как выяснилось, и в случае, когда вместо генерации исключения просто указывается `return`. И вообще, после оператора `if` всегда должен быть `else`.

Насколько я понял из слов технического менеджера, в случае с `else` JVM выполняет некую оптимизацию. Хотелось бы более подробнее узнать об этом моменте - что за оптимизация и где можно подробнее об этом почитать?

Comment: Как вариант: они проверяли вашу уверенность в себе. Наговорили вам бреда, а вы и поверили.

Comment: Честно говоря, я бы даже скобочки для этого  if () не стал бы  писать.

Comment: Про "некую оптимизацию" - бред. Вероятно кто-то со стороны что-то ляпнул, а они недопоняли. Сами же разобраться не смогли, т.к. компиляторы никто не писал из них никогда. Уверяю, практически везде байт-код у обоих примеров будет идентичен, независимо от языка. Соответственно ни о какой дополнительной оптимизации потом не может идти и речи.

Comment: Ребята, спасибо вам всем большое за ответы! Теперь буду знать, что и такое на собеседованиях бывает!

Comment: А почему вы пишите ваш `if` вот так: numbers == null || numbers.length < 2
и не делаете перебор массива для поиска второго по величине массива?

Comment: @АндрейКулик вопрос был задан год назад, почти наверняка автор вам не ответит. )

Comment: @АндрейКулик чтобы найти 2-ое число, этих чисел должно быть минимум два, вот вначале и проверяется что чисел не меньше двух, иначе бросается исключение

Answer (score 51, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу @VladD: я скомпилировал следующий класс с помощью java 8:

```
public class IfElse {
    public int getSecondMaxNumber1(int[] numbers) {
        if (numbers == null || numbers.length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return numbers[1];
    }

    public int getSecondMaxNumber2(int[] numbers) {
        if (numbers == null || numbers.length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return numbers[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Видно, что байткод методов абсолютно одинаковый:

```
$ javap -c IfElse.class
Compiled from "IfElse.java"
public class IfElse {
  public IfElse();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public int getSecondMaxNumber1(int[]);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: ifnull        10
       4: aload_1
       5: arraylength
       6: iconst_2
       7: if_icmpge     18
      10: new           #2                  // class java/lang/IllegalArgumentException
      13: dup
      14: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/IllegalArgumentException."<init>":()V
      17: athrow
      18: aload_1
      19: iconst_1
      20: iaload
      21: ireturn

  public int getSecondMaxNumber2(int[]);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: ifnull        10
       4: aload_1
       5: arraylength
       6: iconst_2
       7: if_icmpge     18
      10: new           #2                  // class java/lang/IllegalArgumentException
      13: dup
      14: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/IllegalArgumentException."<init>":()V
      17: athrow
      18: aload_1
      19: iconst_1
      20: iaload
      21: ireturn
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Нет, нигде нет никакого правила по поводу обязательного `else`.

Наоборот, для конкретно вашего случая форма `if` без `else` лучше, так как не увеличивает без толку глубину вложенности, а акцентирует внимание на том, что код сначала проверяет параметры, и после этого выполняется как есть. В предложенном варианте с `else` код всего метода обладал бы добавочной глубиной вложенности из-за тривиальной проверки в начале.

Даже если бы в недрах JVM была бы оптимизация, выполняющая код с `else` скорее, всё равно правильнее было бы писать не так, как оптимальнее (расход времени на условный оператор порядка наносекунды, так что много вы не выиграете), а [как понятнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416666/10105). Непродуманная оптимизация — причина всех бед.

Устройтесь в нормальную компанию, в этой технические специалисты никуда не годятся.

---

P. S.: Поскольку смысл кода что с else, что без одинаков, есть хорошие шансы, что с подключенными оптимизациями java сгенерирует для обоих вариантов в точности одинаковый промежуточный код. Попробуйте! (У меня нет компилятора java под рукой.)

Answer (score 24):

Радуйтесь что туда не попали. К примеру в исходниках jdk никакого else нет.

`java.lang.Object#wait(long, int)` из jdk 1.8 к примеру.

```
public final void wait(long timeout, int nanos) throws InterruptedException {
    if (timeout < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
    }

    if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && timeout == 0)) {
        timeout++;
    }

    wait(timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере это только делает лишние хлопоты, соображайте так

```
public int getSecondMaxNumber(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        //если условие выполнится значит
        //вылетит исключение которое прервет эту функцию
        //а значит else тут будет лишним
    }
    // именно здесь логика получения второго макс. числа
}
```

Возьмем такой пример

```
i = 1;

if(i == 1){
  //выполняем действие, но это действие не будет прерывать функцию
}
if(i == 2){
  //получается джава будет сравнивать еще раз, не зависимо от того выполнилась ли i == 1
}
//дабы джава не сравнивала еще раз обернем в else

if(i == 1){

}else

if(i == 2){

}
```

В таких случаях используется else.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, это как-то связано с механизмом branch prediction.
Предположим, ваша функция будет выполнена много-много раз.

Очевидно, что код идущий в блоке else будет выполнен на порядок чаще чем тело блока if.

И вот на основании этой информации могут быть выполнены некоторые оптимизации, вроде заинлайнить вызовы методов в блоке else или заинлайнить весь ваш метод в вышестоящий цикл. Или проверка вообще выкинута.

Но это только мои догадки. Возможно они что-то об этом слышали и пытались не к месту козырнуть своими знаниями.
Да и вообще бред придираться к этому на собеседовании.

Comment: Странные у вас догадки. В подобной ситуации что с else, что без else - компилятор сгенерирует абсолютно одинаковый код.