# Цикл For или While

Tags: java

Какой цикл больше нагружает систему? For или While.
Каким циклом пользоваться предпочтительней, часто одну и ту же операцию можно сделать и используя и от и другой

Comment: Это не критично для системы. Для компилятора - это примерно один и тот же набор команд. Тут скорее вопрос в логике и читаемости кода. Хотелось бы увидеть фрагмент кода. И тогда можно решить какой цикл предпочтителен для данной конкретной ситуации.

Comment: Во-первых, они одинаковы, а во-вторых, джава - это немного не тот язык, для которого имеет смысл спрашивать о подобных вещах. Или имелся в виду foreach?

Comment: Кто за закрытие голосовал - почему??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас нет особо большой разницы. Для понимания: цикл `while (i<10)` при компиляции превратится в цикл `for (;i<10;)`.

Answer (score 11):

Вы опоздали с вашим вопросом лет эдак на 30-40.

Сейчас никакой разницы нет, вообще. Компиляторы умные, и если смысл кода по сути один и тот же, обычно производят [одинаковый байткод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432721/10105).

Кроме того, даже если бы производительность разных видов циклов и отличалась, расходы времени на управление циклами составляют порядка нескольких наносекунд. «Оптимизация» такого толка вам ничего не принесёт: расходы на запуск приложения (чтение его из файловой системы) на несколько порядков больше.

[Преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) Оптимизируйте лучше алгоритмы и структуры данных. И не забывайте о [читаемости кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416666/10105), она в миллионы раз важнее потенциального выигрыша в одну процессорную инструкцию.