# if–else или if not – какой код удобнее читать?

Tags: рефакторинг

В чужом коде часто встречаю логику валидации обязательного условия, оформленную так:

```
if (обязательное условие) {
    // много
    // много десятков
    // строк
    // основного
    // кода
} else {
    // одна строка записи об ошибке в лог
    // и ещё одна – return или throw или выход, итого две.
}
```

Мне такое оформление не нравится, т.к. в логике явно есть основной поток, и опциональные вылеты, если какое-то условие fail. И кажется, что углубление ещё на один индент тут ни к чему. Я такие моменты записывал бы так:

```
if ( !обязательное условие) {
    // одна строка записи об ошибке в лог
    // и ещё одна – return или throw или выход, итого две.
}

// дальше много строк основного кода
```

Есть ли помимо моего интуитивного чувства логичная аргументация или общепринятая практика в пользу одного из вариантов?

Comment: Я в подавляющем большинстве случае пользуюсь вторым вариантом. И лишнего отступа нет, и логика не "размазывается". Это дело называется "guard code" (или "guard clause", [судя по Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science))). По поводу общепринятости - тут разве что статистику собирать.

Comment: [Немного по связанной теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432713/10105).

Comment: `unless` (Ruby)! Ну, можно ещё [`if-not` (Clojure)](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-not).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **А**

  `+` избавляемся от восклицательных знаков,

  `-` получаем лишнюю вложенность кода,

  `-` не всегда понятно, что значит «не баланс».

  ```
  if ( balance ){
      // pay
      // and
      // get
      // the
      // food
  }else{
      return("go away")
  }
  ```
- **B**

  `+` возвращаемся сразу, без лишней вложенности,

  `-` восклицательный знак,

  `-` не всегда понятно, что значит «не баланс».

  ```
  if ( !balance ){
      return ("go away")
  }
  // pay
  // and
  // get
  // the
  // food
  ```
- **C**

  переименуем условие:

  `+` по имени переменной сразу понятно, что мы имеем в виду,

  `+` нет лишней вложенности кода,

  `-` кодирование отрицания в имени переменной.

  ```
  if (notEnoughBalance){
      return ("go away");
  }

  // pay
  // and
  // get
  // the
  // food
  ```
- **D**

  переименуем условие, `EnoughBalance`:

  `+` по имени переменной сразу понятно, что мы имеем в виду,

  `+` нет лишней вложенности кода,

  `+` нет кодирования в имени переменной.

  ```
  if (!EnoughBalance){
      return ("go away");
  }

  // pay
  // and
  // get
  // the
  // food
  ```

Это всё-таки сильно вопрос предпочтений, языка программирования и конкретного проекта. Когда я сам пишу код второпях, часто предпочитаю стиль **B**, но обычно стараюсь писать в стиле **C** (пока не падаю на своих же или чужих костылях, поэтому дополним *правильным* стилем **D**).

Еще один плюс подхода **C**: если аккуратно создавать и называть условия, то, в принципе, не придётся мучиться, например, с тем, что разные языки могут по-разному превращать значения в `bool`.

Стиль **D** на самом деле лучше **C**, поскольку рано или поздно кто-нибудь напишет

```
if (!notEnoughBalance){// тут у вас ломается голова

}
```

Спасибо [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), я никак не мог вспомнить ловушку на которую несколько раз за последние годы натыкался.

В итоге: имя переменной условия или функции, которая возвращает условие не должно  содержать условия правильности, только ее смысл:

- `EnoughMoney`, `AcceptableHeight`, `TooHeavy` допустимы.
- `NotEnoughMoney`,  `NotAcceptableHeight`, `NotTooHeavy` идут лесом.

Пример от, опять же, [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy):

> `notHasAccess` или `hasNotAccess` можно заменить на `isAccessDenied` — то же самое кодирование истинности в имени переменной, но семантически более правильное, поскольку содержит в себе не только отрицание, но и смысл — «доступЗапрещен».

Comment: Вариант C - зло. Имена переменных не должны содержать отрицаний. Лучше отрицание перед переменной, чем отрицание в имени. Надо либо честно ставить отрицание, либо переименовать переменную с использованием других слов.

Comment: @Qwertiy да я вот щас тоже задумался. Иногда натыкался на семантические грабли с ним. С другой стороны, он удобней при систематическом и правильном применении.

Comment: Можно ещё дополнить, что часто можно просто подобрать антоним. Например, `notHasAccess` или `hasNotAccess` можно заменить на `isAccessDenied`. Держи плюсик.

Comment: A вот про приставки `in`/`un` я бы не был слишком категоричен, т. к. они всё-таки образуют законченные слова. Они где-то на границе. Фразу "height is not inacceptable" понять проще, чем "height is not not acceptable" :)

Comment: я не знаю, готов ли я доводить этот ответ до идеала и возможно ли это вообще, но большое спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy но hasAccessDenied это все равно кодирование отрицания (denied) в имени переменной! )

Comment: Да, отрицание. Но без явного слова `not`. Доступ разрешён? Доступ запрещён? Доступ не разрешён? Доступ не запрещён? - Ни одна из этих фраз не вызывает недоумения. А вот обе фразы: Доступ не неразрешён? Доступ не незапрещён? явно звучат так себе и над ними придётся думать. Кстати, в своём примере я заменил `has` на `is`, поскольку с has действительно получается что-то не то...

Answer (score 6):

Применение if/else / if not зависит от контекста применения. Если есть разница операций, но единая часть завершения кода, то требуется использовать первый вариант.

Если при невыполнении какого-то условия продолжение программы (метода) **дальше не имеет смысла**, то логично использовать второй вариант.

Плюсы второго метода при таком контексте применения очевидны. Вам при анализе кода просто легче видеть и держать в голове, при каких условиях выполнение кода завершится, поэтому Вы его и используете. Ведь, по сути, это **граничное условие**, прерывающее основной код.

**Предположим, есть задача:**

Написать метод контроллера, в котором выдать ошибку, если записи нет, а в случае успеха изменить поле name на 1, выполнить сохранение в базу и вывести всю информацию по пользователю. Если пользователя зовут Ivan, то просто сбросить ему пароль, но имя не менять.

```
$user = Users::find($id);

if (!$user) {
   throw new BadRequestException("User not found");
}

if ($user->getName()=="Ivan") {
     $user->setPassword(null);
} else {
     $user->setName(1);
}

$user->save();

var_dump($user->toArray());
```

Тут вопрос логики, ведь так удобно читать данный код и сразу понятно, что если данного пользователя не существует, то выполнение программы будет прервано и читать дальше нет смысла. А представим, что используем if else, тогда получается дополнительная вложенность if, которая усложняет чтение программы и ее наглядность:

```
$user = Users::find($id);

if ($user) {

  if ($user->getName()=="Ivan") {
     $user->setPassword(null);
  } else {
     $user->setName(1);
  }

  $user->save();

  var_dump($user->toArray());

} else {
   throw new BadRequestException("User not found");
}
```

Мы, по сути, здесь основной код программы вынесли в условие, что не совсем верно. Ведь, от этого `$user` может зависеть весь метод контроллера, и придется вынести весь код в if.

*Мне кажется, что нужно избегать **лишней вложенности**, если есть разумный метод решения.*

Answer (score 6):

По моему мнению, в случае «асимметричных» веток, в особенности когда короткая ветка завершает выполнение, нет смысла тянуть её до точки после длинной ветки. Это ухудшает понятность кода, т. к. иначе читатель вынужден держать в голове наличие альтернативного варианта, читая весь код положительной ветки `if`.

Обычно в таких проверках сначала проверяется правильность входных данных, или отсекается «особый» случай (входной параметр равен `null`, задание уже выполняется, приложение уже завершается и т. п.), и дальнейшая часть кода работает с «типичным» случаем.

В альтернативном варианте, когда сначала идёт короткая проверка и выход, читатель может сразу по прочтении условия и действий по выходу из процедуры переключиться на «нормальный» случай и не держать в голове потенциально сложное отложенное задание («нужно ещё будет как-то обработать случай, когда условие не выполняется»).

Лучше не забивать голову читателю кода лишними конструкциями, понять код (без разницы, свой или чужой) непросто и без этого.

Answer (score 4):

В большинстве случаев if с выходом удобнее, поскольку не отправляет весь код на лишний уровень вложенности. С другой стороны, если речь идёт уже о некой вложенной структуре, то я предпочитаю плюс уровень, чем лишний код рядом. И пусть их там хоть пачка будет - цепочку вложенности читать легче, чем смесь линейных конструкций с вложенностью.

Например, я расставлю if'ы так:

```
function sum(a) {
  var res = 0;

  if (!a) {
    return 0;
  }

  for (var r of a) {
    if (r && r.length) {
      for (var x of r) {
        if (x > 0) {
          res += x;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}

sum([[1,2,4,-4,-2,-1],888,[312]])
```

но не так (хотя `if (a)` как-то органично вписывается в структуру - конкретно в этом случае в него можно было обернуть циклы, но в большинстве случаев это не так):

```
function sum(a) {
  var res = 0;

  if (a) {
    for (var r of a) {
      if (!r || !r.length) {
        continue;
      }

      for (var x of r) {
        if (x <= 0) {
          continue;
        }

        res += x;
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}

sum([[1,2,4,-4,-2,-1],888,[312]])
```

PS: Есть ещё [тема про фигурные скобки](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424351/178988).