# Стоит ли создавать локальную переменную, если она нужна всего один раз?

Tags: java

Особенно сложно понять, стоит ли создавать локальную переменную, когда она используется как аргумент метода. Например, у меня есть `ArrayList<Integer>` и я вызываю его метод

`set(int i, Object value);`

Вот так:

```
limit.set(
                    index,
                    limit.get(i)
                            - task.getUnSortListOfVariable().get(i)
                                    .get(maxTop.getFix()).getWeight());
```

limit - это мой `ArrayList<Integer>`

Прошу обратить внимание на второй аргумент:

```
limit.get(i)
                            - task.getUnSortListOfVariable().get(i)
                                    .get(maxTop.getFix()).getWeight()
```

Стоит ли написать:

```
int value = limit.get(i);
value -= task.getUnSortListOfVariable().get(i)
                                    .get(maxTop.getFix()).getWeight();
```

Больше это value нигде в коде использоваться не будет.

Comment: Да она всё равно на стеке создаётся и уничтожится после выхода из скопа. Вопрос чисто удобства и красоты кода.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я понимаю, мне как раз и интересен вопрос правильности, красоты кода. Вот как в данном случае будет правильнее с профессиональной точки зрения?

Comment: Зря минусуете, хороший вопрос в рамках SO (раз уж у нас нет русского Programmers.SE)

Comment: в таком виде - нет. Что такое `value` - не понятно. Из нее вычитается нечто, получаемое огромной цепью вызовов. Если выделять что-то в переменную, то "вычитаемое", и назвать как-то значимо.

Comment: Красивее код вряд ли будет, но зато так будет проще отлаживать, чем когда всё в одну строку. Поставить точку останова можно будет на вызове на отдельной функции, а не для всего выражения.

Comment: @zRrr, а будет лучше если и вычитаемое, и то из чего вычитаю? А потом еще одну локальную переменную, в которую записать результат вычитания и ее уже передать в limit.set()? И еще можно было бы завести локальную переменную для maxTop.getFix(). В общем, интересно насколько детализировано стоит такое выражение разбивать и стоит ли вообще?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров С одной стороны вы проясняете каждый шаг, с другой стороны плодите строки кода и раздуваете метод. Тут важен баланс. А какой он должен быть - решайте согласно своему опыту и опыту коллег.

Comment: Вот тут есть мотивация: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416666/10105

Answer (score 7):

Да, стоит, если это повышает читаемость кода. Лучший код - самодокументированный.

Всего должно быть в меру. Если создавать переменную на каждый чих, то код раздуется и "за деревьями не будет виден лес".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Еще очень интересен один вопрос, но думаю если задать его отдельно, то заминусят. Поэтому рискну задать в комментариях. А есть ведь наверняка ситуации, когда от правил "красивого" когда можно и даже нужно отступать? Не могли бы вы поделиться опытом, привести пример таких ситуаций. Или подсказать где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Не спешите принимать мой ответ, за день-два вам могут еще ответить. У любого правила есть исключения и ситуаций таких у вас будет много. Самое простое - `goto` считается абсолютным злом, и тем не менее, иногда (1 раз на миллион) его использование сократит объем ветвлений вдвое и упростит понимание логики кода. Почитать об этом можно в гугле ;-)

Comment: понимаю что таких ситуаций много, хотелось бы научиться их распознавать. У меня проект не двигается, я все пытаюсь его отрефакторить, а может быть у меня как раз такие ситуации и встретились. В гугле искал, по запросу "когда можно НЕ следовать правилам красивого кода" и всем подобным запросам выдает только как собственно писать красивый код, что это такое и каким правилам надо следовать.

Comment: Взгляните на приложение глазами заказчика. Он вам заплатит за красивый код? Или скорее заплатит за нужный ему функционал, отсутствие багов и простоту расширения?

Comment: за красивый код вряд ли заплатит :) Но ведь именно он помогает достичь простоты расширяемости? Отсюда - можно добавлять новый функционал. Да и ошибок в таком коде скорее всего будет меньше. Тем не менее у меня есть один знакомый программист, работает вроде в серьезной фирме. так вот, он мне показывал их проект, там методы по 200 строк.. Больше у меня знакомых программистов нет, сам я еще только учусь в университете, а этот единственный - недостаточно авторитетен. А писать хороший код жутко хочется, потому что без этого умения все мои проекты останавливаются и гибнут.

Comment: Вот когда к нам кандидат пришел и показал 1 метод на 5000+ строк, а второй на 9000+, вот тогда мы выпали. А 200 строк это фигня и даже в пределах нормы. Не зацикливайтесь на красоте. Красота это недостижимый идеал, где потратив день вы сделаете лучше на 50%, потратив второй на 25%, третий - на 12.5% .. вы поняли к чему я клоню - 100% никогда не будет. Надо вовремя остановиться. А еще у вас будут дедлайны, когда приложение нужно к пятнице и вам бы успеть сделать хоть как, чтобы без ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам за подробные разъяснения!